# how to change the color of textlabel to UITableViewCellStyleValue1 color

Tags: objective-c, xcode

this is a noob question.i subclassed my table view cell in interface builder and created a table view.what i want is  to change the color of the textlabel to UITableViewCellStyleValue1 color(light blue).since i created the cell in .nib file.i m not able to use cell.detailtextlabel.text.could u guys help me out.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

}
UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UIImageView *imgV = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
UILabel *label=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3];

 NSDictionary *dToAccess = [self.listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[lbl setText:[dToAccess valueForKey:@"title"]];
NSUInteger intVal = [[dToAccess valueForKey:@"rating"] integerValue];
switch (intVal) {
    case 0:
        [imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0star.png"]];
        [label setText:@"Snitt 0"];
        label.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        break;
    case 1:
        [imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1star.png"]];
        [label setText:@"Snitt 1"];
        break;
    case 2:
        [imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2star.png"]];
        [label setText:@"Snitt 2"];
        break;
    case 3:
        [imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3star.png"]];
         [label setText:@"Snitt 3"];
        break;
    case 4:
        [imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4star.png"]];
        [label setText:@"Snitt 4"];
        break;
    case 5:
        [imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5star.png"]];
        [label setText:@"Snitt 5"];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
CGSize size = [lbl.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16] forWidth:205 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
[lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, size.width, 43)];

[imgV setFrame:CGRectMake(5+size.width+5, 4, 118, 36)];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you clarify your question.  are you trying to change the color of your `label.text`? What do you mean to the color of `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`?

Comment: i ve set label.text as blue color.which gives me a navy blue..what is want is to change the color to light blue(color similar when set UITableViewCellStyleValue1 in detail textlabel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the detail label cell color for `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` by doing:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"resuse"];
UIColor *lightBlueColor = cell.detailTextLabel.textColor;
```

which can be broken down into it's RGB values and alpha by doing:

```
const float* colors = CGColorGetComponents( lightBlueColor.CGColor );
```

It's up to you if you want to hardcode the values in code or just compute it every time.  I'd say hardcode would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is getting hold of the label on which to set the color.  If you've rolled your own cell, a quick thing to do is give your label a tag value in the nib, (look for it along with the other view properties of your label).

Then when you're configuring the cell, get the label like this:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:16];  // 16 is a unique in the view, non-zero int that you make up yourself
label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

The alternative is to connect outlets from your nib to properties on a custom cell, but tags might be a simpler way to start out.